# How to use Forms authentication and Azure AD Authentication at the same time

Tags: azure, authentication, active-directory, asp.net-identity, owin

I have a Web forms Webapp that supports normal Forms Authentication login, that connects to a database. I want to add an extra option for users to be able to login with their Microsoft account, while still having the option to log in normally.

I know I want to use Owin and OpenID connect for this. I also know I want to match credentials from the ID-Token after logging in with Microsoft, with existing users in my own database, for users to be able to log in with both options.

My concern is, that I am not able to implement these things at the same time. For example, from what I have read, authentication mode="Forms" need to be authentication mode="None" for Azure AD authentication to work.

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate to Azure AD from your forms application?

Comment: Hi @William, please let us know if the issue is already fixed or still looking for any solution.